# -[ECSlidingViewController notifyWhenInteractionChangesUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: unrecognized-selector, ecslidingviewcontroller

I recently updated Xcode to version 11.3.1 and after that i am not able to run my application. I've been getting the following exception:

2020-02-11 16:13:04.767795-0600 UVM[5204:80616] -[ECSlidingViewController notifyWhenInteractionChangesUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8258016c00

2020-02-11 16:13:04.785346-0600 UVM[5204:80616] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ECSlidingViewController notifyWhenInteractionChangesUsingBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8258016c00'

It was working fine before i did the Xcode update. Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the following method was deprecated and it was the one throwing the exception during launch.

```
- (void)notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:(void(^)(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>context))handler {
    self.coordinatorInteractionEnded = handler;
}
```

It was in ECSlidingViewController.m

If we comment out that method and add the following method the app is working fine again:

```
- (void)notifyWhenInteractionChangesUsingBlock:(nonnull void (^)(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> _Nonnull))handler {
    self.coordinatorInteractionEnded = handler;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, having the same issue. Appreciate sooooo much!!